# Envio duplicado de formulário com upload - JS com FormData

Tags: javascript, formdata

Fala, galera!
Estou com um problema com o FormData para envio de arquivos via AJAX usando FormData. Fiz um cadastro de imagens que após carregar uma imagem, o usuário pode carregar uma segunda imagem. No entanto, carregando a página, ao cadastrar a primeira imagem, vai tudo bem, na segunda imagem, ela é enviada 2 vezes, na terceira imagem, 3 vezes e assim sucessivamente.
Ao dar um refresh na página, reinicia-se o ciclo. Dei como exemplo esse formulário, mas isso ocorre com todos os formulários que envio com esse método.
É como se a cada clique de envio, o DOM fosse duplicado e cada "cópia" realizasse as mesmas tarefas.
Testei em outros navegadores, mesma coisa.

Segue abaixo o código.

HTML

```
<form id="form_banner" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row" id="conteudo">
        <div class="col s12 input-field">
            <div class="config_img_g">
                <div class="arquivo_midia">Novo banner <span>(Formatos jpg ou png com até 2Mb de tamanho)</span>    </div>
                <input type="file" name="banner" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" class="dropify fileSize">
            </div>
        </div>                  
        <div class="col s12 m3">
            <button id="banner_salvar" class="btn btn_l confirma">Cadastrar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS

```
function banner_Salva(){
    $('#form_banner').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let formData = new FormData(this);
        if($('.dropify-render').html()!=""){ //Se houver alguma imagem, esse objeto é preenchido com uma imagem. Verificação apenas para não enviar o campo vazio.
            $.ajax({
                type:           "POST",
                url:            "https://"+dominio+"/banner-salva",
                cache:          false,
                contentType:    false,
                processData:    false,
                data:           formData,

                beforeSend:function(){
                    $("#modal").html("<h6 class=\"modal_tit\">Guardando as informações...</h6><div class=\"progress\"><div class=\"indeterminate\"></div></div>")
                    $("#modal").modal("open")
                },

                success: function(retorno){
                    if(retorno.trim() != "OK"){
                        $("#modal").modal("close"),
                        Swal.fire({
                            title:  "Ops!",
                            html:   retorno,
                            icon:   "error",
                            confirmButtonText: "OK"
                        })
                    }
                    
                    $("#modal").modal("close")
                    //As próximas linhas tratam a ferramenta dropfy para deixá-lo pronto (limpo/vazio)
                    $(".dropify-preview")           .removeAttr("style", "display-block")
                    $(".dropify-preview")           .attr("style", "none")
                    $(".dropify-render")            .html("")
                    $(".dropify-filename-inner")    .html("")                           
                }       
            })
            
        }else{
            Swal.fire({
                title:  "Ops!",
                html:   "O banner precisa de uma imagem para ser carregado!",
                icon:   "error",
                confirmButtonText: "OK"
            })
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: O problema é que você colocou o $('#form_banner').submit dentro de uma função, todas vez que chamar a função ele cria um evento, cria a rotina do submit dentro do onload da pagina e chama a função por ele... ou seja inverte a coisa :-)

Comment: Fala, Marcelo! Foi exatamente o que descobri! Rsrs... Estava reestruturando o arquivo para vir postar a solução... Tenso, viu! Hahaha!!! Mas valeu assim mesmo, para confirmar minha observação! Obrigado pela dica, amigo!

Comment: Boas... apanhei muito nisso aí... olha presta atenção que eventos jquery são criados a cada solicitação, mesmo dentro de outros eventos uma opção que você pode estudar é o $(obj).off ele desliga os eventos do objeto, mas é bom ler sobre ele para aplicar da maneira correta, boa sorte ai.